# Google Places API results in ListView

Tags: android, database, google-maps, listview

I am writing an app where I am searching for local restaurants (around where the device is at the moment). I was advised to check out Google Places API. However, I am in a college town and it seems that many of the places I want to be searched are not found using Google Places.

Is there a way to search a predefined list of restaurants? Is it good practice to pull it from a website server? Im just getting started with this and would really appreciate any help.

I want the user to be able to type "McDonald's" in the Search Dialog, my app search for all close McDonald's and return a list that can be formatted into a ListView. There is also a "Closest" option, which will return the top 20 closest restaurants around in order from closest to farthest.

How should I start doing this? Any help would be helpful! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One thing you could do is add the local places to Google Places using the Places API, through [Google Places for Business](http://www.google.com/placesforbusiness), or [Google Map Maker](http://google.com/mapmaker). Once they're approved, which is usually fairly quickly, they're available for use in the Places API.

If you don't want to go that route, there's three articles in Google's code documentation on using PHP and MySQL to display map markers.
http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/articles.html

They can be easily adapted to your server side language of choice. These are for Maps API V3, the JavaScript API, but could be adapted for Android as well.